# Razor cshtml table multiple thead tr's

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to build one table with multiple thead tr's but I am getting `tobdy element was not closed` and `foreach block is missing a close }` Is there better way to do this?

```
    <table id="kendoGrid">
        @{foreach (titleViewModel objTitle in Model)
            {
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @objTitle.Name
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Meeting Date</th>
                        <th>Type</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (DataViewModel objData in objMeeting.PanelsMeetingViewModel)
                        {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@objData.Name</td>
                            <td>@objData.Date</td>
                            <td>@objData.Type</td>
                        </tr>
                        }
                <tbody>
        }
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Try this.

```
<table id="kendoGrid">
    @foreach (titleViewModel objTitle in Model)
    {
        <thead>
          <tr>
              @objTitle.Name
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Meeting Date</th>
              <th>Type</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          @foreach (DataViewModel objData in objMeeting.PanelsMeetingViewModel)
          {
          <tr>
              <td>@objData.Name</td>
              <td>@objData.Date</td>
              <td>@objData.Type</td>
          </tr>
          }
        </tbody>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: I am still getting the tbody was not closed.

Comment: I have updated the answer please check now. @Jefferson